# Access already created view controllers in a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a `UIPageViewController` for displaying images, and I download the images asynchronously and throw them into the gallery when they're ready (but you're still able to go to the page in the gallery where the image *will* be).

My issue is that, when the image *does* load, I need to supply it for the view controller it corresponds to. Right now, I add it to an `NSCache` instance, and when `UIPageViewController`'s data source method `viewControllerAfterViewController:` is called, I check if the image for the view controller being requested has already been downloaded (is in the cache) and if it is, I call `initWithImage:` on the specific view controller, passing the downloaded image.

My issue is with when `viewControllerAfterViewController:` is called and the image *hasn't* been downloaded yet. Right now I just load the view controller without the image, and when the `imageDidFinishDownloading:` delegate method is called, I try to supply the view controller with the image.

However, it seems that even though `UIPageViewController` asks for the next view controller the previous gets displayed (i.e.: when I get to the 3rd page, it requests the 4th page's view controller) *I'm not able to access this requested view controller that I hand off*.

If I access `pageViewController.viewControllers`, the count of the `NSArray` is *never* more than 1. So even though it seems like it should have 2 (the currently showing view controller and the next one that it requested), it only ever has one, the currently visible view controller.

The problem is that *I need the other one*. The image finishes downloading, and I really only have two options.

1. Give it to my `NSCache`, so *when the init method is called* for the view controller, it is handed off.
2. In the event that it has *already* been `init`ed, hand it off to the view controller that's already been `init`ed.

But 1 doesn't always work, as sometimes the `init` method is called when there's no image yet (it hasn't finished downloading), so we'd sometimes depend on 2, but `pageViewController.viewControllers` only holds the current visible view controller.

So there's basically this third situation where the view controller has already been `init`ed without an image, and the image finishes downloading and I want to assign it to that view controller, but I'm currently on the one before it, and my only reference to the view controllers in the `UIPageViewController` is on the current visible one.

How do I handle 3? I need to assign something to a view controller *but I can't find any way to access that view controller*.

Comment: How are you correlating the controllers and the images in the cache?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sorry Josh, I wasn't home yet and wanted to give you a decent answer  from something other than my phone. To answer your question every view controller created is given an `index` property in the subclass with a corresponding value, which also serves as the key for the image in the NSCache. When I create the controller I check if there's an object in the cache for the view controller's index, if not I create it without the image. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I see. And you can't get use the index because the page view controller's array doesn't seem to have the full list of view controllers. Makes sense. I'm away from keyboard now myself at the moment, but I'll try to look into this.

Comment: The docs say that the view controllers array is "The array of view controllers contains the content view controllers that **are currently being displayed.**" The page controller is not necessarily keeping track of VCs whose views are offscreen for you. You will have to manage them yourself, in your data source or elsewhere. Seems like you could also just key the images with the VCs, which is why I asked about that. So the answer to your title question is "you can't", as far as I can tell. You need to modify your design, which is why Timonthy Moose suggested something like futures.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like a future from [PMConcurrency](https://github.com/dpratt/PMConcurrency) to do this. A future is just an object that promises to return your image as soon as it's available. So by giving the future to your view controller instead of the image, you don't need to worry about when the image arrives.

Your view controller's initializer would look something like this:

```
- initWithImageFuture:(PMFuture *)future
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [[future onMainThread] onComplete:^(id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                _image = result;
            }
        }];
    }
    return self;
}
```

By adding an `onComplete` block to the future, the view controller will receive the image as soon as it's available (immediately if the image is already downloaded). Futures run in the background by default, so you'd use `onMainThread` to have the result returned on the main thread.

So instead of populating your cache with images, you'd populate it with image futures. There are several ways to create futures, but the block-based one is pretty simple:

```
PMFuture *imageFuture = [PMFuture futureWithBlock:^id{
    UIImage *image = ...; // Your image fetching code here
    return image;        
}];

[myCache setObject:imageFuture forKey:myImageKey];
```

Comment: I appreciate the info, but this really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @dougsmith I would think accessing your view controller through a callback would qualify as an answer.

Comment: To expound on what Tim is saying, you can manage all of the details of populating the UIImageViews on your yet-to-be-displayed controller entirely inside itself. All you need to do is set up some mechanism to download your image using either block callbacks or PMFutures and then set the image properties using that callback mechanism. If you do this, you don't need to access the reference to your next view controller from the UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar sort of function but I load the image in the view controller that is displaying the image (the VC handed to the UIPageViewController).  In your context I guess I'd had the image ID info and the NSCache object to the VC.  That isn't what you want to do of course, but just something to think about.

Originally I tried to handle image loading in the parent like you are.  As I recall, I kept a weak pointer to the target view controller.  When the image arrived if the VC was still alive I could set the UIImageView property.

Comment: I find UIPageViewController is so quick to kill view controllers off so I'm hesitant to do anything that takes time in any of the view controllers.